# JSON Data into a list displaying both key and values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a list using the Data that I got from a JSON and dynamically populate an ul

My code so far

```
let userInfo = [];
const containerInfo = document.getElementById("result");
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
.then(response=> response.json())
.then(data => {
  userInfo = data;

  for(info in userInfo){
    console.log(info)
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let node = document.createTextNode(info)
    li.appendChild(node)
    containerInfo.appendChild(li)
    
  }
  console.log(userInfo.id)
})
```

Expected Output:

```
userId: number
id: number
title: string
body: string
```

Sadly I couldn't find a way to get both, I tried using different approaches but I don't know how to have this kind of output:

```
userId: 1
id: 1
title: sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit
body: quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto
```

I can do it in a table by manually putting a string but I want to make a list with both in a way that's dynamic using only javascript

Comment: Hey, it's hard to understand what the expected output should look like. The endpoint you are hitting is sending only one item, so there is nothing to iterate in the loop

Comment: `let node = document.createTextNode(``userID: ${info.userId}<br />id: ${info.id}<br />title: ${info.title}<br />body: ${info.body}``)`? (replace double back-ticks with single-back-ticks)

Comment: Do you just want to log these variables in console? Or do you ask how to get these variables and append them into a list?

Comment: I want to append them into a list like the expected output I've posted. I've made a console log just to be sure everything was working fine

Comment: How many items are in `userInfo`? If it's just one, then replace your loop with a loop over the `Object.keys(userInfo.info)`; othewise you could add a loop over these inside your current loop and create your `li` elements within the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `Object.entries()`.

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkq10/uefvjLtx/)

```
for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(userInfo)){
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let node = document.createTextNode(key +': '+ value)
    li.appendChild(node)
    containerInfo.appendChild(li)
    console.log(key +': '+ value)
}
```